# Help clarify the appropriate [behavior]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request

[behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behavior) (600+ Questions, 5 Followers) does not sound useful at all and should therefore disappear.

Comment: Doesn't seem to add much eh?

Comment: But I'm a 'behavior' expert! :P

Comment: I thought the tag was there so we could flag poor behaviour from the poster! :)

Comment: @MattCoubrough Such questions are tagged with [poor-behavior].

Comment: Who are the people that are following this? Can we maybe get a feature that notifies those people about a burnination request so they can explain their reason? This should get us some insight about what they thing the tag is and why its worth following.

Answer (score 24):

I'm not 100% sure, but I think [in some languages/frameworks a 'behavior' is a specific construct](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flash/cs/using/WSd60f23110762d6b883b18f10cb1fe1af6-7b52a.html), at a similar level as a 'delegate' or an 'event handler'.

Of course the tag wiki says nothing of the sort.  It also seems completely **wrong** for [behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behaviors) to be a synonym of [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behavior) as currently described, since the former almost certainly is discussing a language/framework construct and not

> the output of a program contrasted against programmer or user expectations

which is straight from the current wiki for [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behavior)

Probably some questions should be tagged as one of:

- [actionscript-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-behavior) (doesn't currently exist, I suspect this meaning was the original inhabitant of [behaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behaviors)
- [servicebehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servicebehavior)
- [uidynamicbehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uidynamicbehavior)
- [uicollisionbehavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uicollisionbehavior)
- [drupal-debehaviors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drupal-debehaviors)
- [wpf-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wpf-behavior) (which should probably have a synonym [silverlight-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/silverlight-behavior))
- Any of the others that come up from typing "behavior" in the [Tag Search](https://stackoverflow.com/tags?tab=name), I can't seem to link to a search result, it's all AJAXy

Comment: probably also [tag:bdd] Behavior Driven Design, or (sometimes also called) Behavior Driven Testing

Comment: @mihi: Those sound more like tags for Programmers.SE.

Comment: Erlang also has `-behaviour`s

Answer (score 3):

Questions should **not** be retagged to

- [undefined-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior)
- [unspecified-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unspecified-behavior)
- etc

as questions whether the language standard specifies behavior for a particular coding pattern fall in the scope of [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer).

[Related discussion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258427/merge-and-synonymize-undefined-behavior-into-language-lawyer?lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

This shouldn't be burned. As [Ben's answer notes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258410/help-clarify-the-appropriate-behavior/258425#258425), Behaviors are notable concepts in quite a number of different languages / frameworks, and thus this tag can be disambiguated merely by combining it with one of those tags.

If folks feel like retagging the remaining questions that cover this ground, it can perhaps be removed at that time; otherwise, I wouldn't worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

Burn this tag. The current tag wiki [excerpt] basically says

> For programs that behave different from what I expected

which applies to *all* the "my code does not work" questions that SO gets daily. This excerpt should be edited urgently. There are too many questions that use this tag wrongly, e.g. [jQuery strange behavior in seperate .js file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22363154/jquery-strange-behavior-in-seperate-js-file).

I think it's better to re-tag the question to framework/language-specific "behaviour" tags than to leave this too generic one float around.