# Merge and synonymize undefined-behavior into language-lawyer

Tags: discussion, status-declined, retag-request

Apart from a handful of FAQs (like [this C++ one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2397984/103167)) that provide an explanation of the term "Undefined Behavior" and its practical effects, all other uses of [undefined-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) are actually asking for a citation of some language specification which makes the behavior of a particular coding pattern well-defined, implementation-defined, unspecified, or undefined.  As such, these requests for standard citations fall into [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer).

Let's kill [undefined-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) as an independent tag by removing it from the FAQs, where the tag is not needed because the phrase appears prominently in the question title, and re-tagging the rest to [language-lawyer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-lawyer), including creation of a synonym.

(In fact, the aforementioned FAQ survived quite nicely without having [undefined-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) or [unspecified-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unspecified-behavior) until people [started cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258410/103167) of [behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/behavior), which also was added recently... these tags add nothing to the FAQ)

Comment: Just because there is a large amount of overlap between [language-lawyer] and [undefined-behavior] does not make one tag useless. Why, exactly, do we need to get rid of [undefined-behavior]? What is *wrong* with that tag?

Comment: @cody: tags go on questions, whether code is undefined behavior or not should be stated in an answer, but the one asking the question hardly ever knows

Comment: I checked with the folks in the C++ Lounge to see what they thought.  Their verdict: a resounding "meh."  See http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10/conversation/undefined-behavior-tag-verdict-meh

Comment: ... and it's quite an impressive feat to find something even the Lounge won't bash, so congratulations.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: And I submit it's even worse than what DeadMG said, that they don't know to use [tag:undefined-behavior].  Wven if they do tag the question [tag:undefined-behavior], it's equally likely that it really involves [tag:unspecified-behavior], and it will definitely take a [tag:language-lawyer] to sort it out.

Comment: @CodyGray All programs are written to avoid UB. All questions regarding programming could possibly use that tag, so the tag is meaningless.

Answer (score 9):

There's nothing especially disruptive about this tag.

Let's apply some of the recent metrics that the community has been using to evaluate tags such as `div`, shall we?

1. Can a user be an expert in Undefined Behavior?  I'd say so.
2. Might someone follow this tag? I might.
3. Can it effectively categorize a question?  No doubt.

Three for three.  I'd say it stays.

Comment: I think it miserably fails on #3, though (see my answer).  Also, can a user be an expert in one of these tags but not the other?  No.

Comment: Ben, your answer uses as evidence tags that don't even exist.

Comment: There is [tag:unspecified-behavior], which is presumably an attempt to describe an unspecified result in a way that's parallel with [tag:undefined-behavior].

Comment: Those two can either be synonymized, or unspecified-behavior can be removed entirely.  At 22 instances, now would be a good time to do so.

Comment: Which two?  unspecified behavior is synonymous with unspecified result or unspecified sequencing, but quite different from undefined-behavior.  It could be forwarded to [tag:language-lawyer] though

Comment: unspecified-result and unspecified-sequencing do not exist.  Language-lawyer is more broad.

Comment: Right, hence I have no idea which pair you want to make synonyms...

Comment: unspecified-behavior and undefined-behavior, although unspecified-behavior is not really a well-known term at all, whereas undefined-behavior is.  Suggest removal of unspecified-behavior.

Comment: Those definitely aren't synonyms.  The C++ Standard actually uses the phrase "unspecified behavior" to mean a combination of unspecified results or unspecified sequencing.  But clearly they all are [tag:language-lawyer] except the ["Please explain these terms to a non-lawyer" FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397984/undefined-unspecified-and-implementation-defined-behavior).

Comment: If they're all valid terms used in the spec in the way that you describe, then they're all valid tags.  Trying to mash them all together under one generic umbrella doesn't confer any real benefit, that I can see.

Comment: That doesn't follow.  Questions are invariably about the boundary between these.  Even the definition FAQ is more than anything about the difference between them.  You can't have a question about [tag:undefined-behavior] other than the trivial "When the compiler encounters undefined behavior, is it allowed to XYZ?" (Trivial, because the answer is YES irrespective of what XYZ is).

Comment: +1: This answer has my support, but I'm not terribly fussed either way.

Comment: "_Can a user be an expert in Undefined Behavior?_" No. That would be a language expert. There is nothing special about UB.

Comment: Can a mechanical engineer be specialized in forces? Can a medical doctor be specialized in diseases? Or health? Or not killing patient while treating him? **Any programming task is based on using the specification to achieve a particular result; that is guaranteeing a particular behavior** (might be set of allowable behaviors if there is non determinism as in with threads) that is avoiding UB. Avoiding UB is inherent with writing correct programs. Putting UB appart with a tag seems batcrazy.

Answer (score -2):

Yes, let's do this.  Questions other than the FAQ never ask about undefined behavior.  Even a question worded as

> Does this piece of code produce undefined behavior?

is really this in disguise:

> According to the standard/specification for the language I'm using, is the behavior of this code (a) well-defined (b) implementation-defined (c) unspecified result and/or sequence of execution (d) undefined?  Are stronger guarantees provided by non-language standards such as POSIX, in environments which conform to them?  Are stronger de-facto guarantees provided in common environments such as Microsoft Windows?

Adding a tag according to just one of those options is counter-productive.  A question could get (for example) [c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) [undefined-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/undefined-behavior) [unspecified-behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unspecified-behavior) (implementation-specific is covered by [portability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/portability))... and then there are no tags left for actually describing the topic.

There aren't questions about one or the other of these, only about the boundary lines between them.

These boundary questions properly fall under `language-lawyer`.  (The list differs slightly in languages other than C and C++, but the overall result is the same)

Comment: You haven't adequately stated your case for "counter-productive," especially since you used tags in your hypothetical example that don't really exist.  Moderator action on The Stack is motivated by solving problems that are actively harming the site.  How is the [undefined-behavior] tag actively harming the site?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: It's counter-productive because [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23929360/no-build-error-when-including-header-file-containing-variable-definition-in-2) [end](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23763748/c-using-a-reference-to-the-variable-being-defined) [up](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23260705/program-crashes-due-to-undefined-behavior) [missing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22977043/do-these-syntactically-correct-c-statements-carry-any-meaning) the tags they should have, because we tell them putting one of these keywords in the tag list is enough

Comment: Um, what tags are those questions missing, exactly?

Comment: First I just added compilation and multiple-inclusions, second is getting self-reference and variable-scope, third one the OP has learned that "undefined behavior" is a fancy way of saying "I have a bug", to wit: "I think it's due to undefined behavior", and was crowd-sourcing his bug hunt.  Fourth one has nothing to do with undefined behavior at all.

Comment: So you're saying that those four questions don't need the undefined-behavior tag?  FTFY.  As I've explained elsewhere, the fact that some people misuse a tag doesn't automatically make it a bad tag.

Comment: @Robert: Well, doesn't it seem odd that all questions which are [tag:c++] [tag:undefined-behavior] with no other tags actually shouldn't be using that tag?  That's the only filter I used to find those... [search for `[C++] [undefined-behavior]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b%20undefined-behavior) and ignore questions that have more tags.  I thought the utter inability of a tag to stand alone was a mark of not really being a tag.

Comment: Well, the first question in that list doesn't deserve the tag (I removed the tag and dupe-closed the question), but the next two do.  Are you sure you understand what the tag means?

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I don't think that use of `[tag:undefined-behavior]` for "look at my wall of code and spot my undefined behavior (aka bug)" is an appropriate use of the tag (third question).  Second question fits fine in [tag:language-lawyer]; the OP again doesn't know whether it is undefined, unspecified, or well-defined behavior, he just picked one of those at random to tag his question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: I just gave a real answer to that second question, as it turns out it involves all three of undefined-behavior, unspecified-behavior, and well-defined behavior.  There's zero reason for one of those to appear in the tags but not the others, and putting all three in the tags is using up all the tags unhelpfully.

Comment: Why would well-defined-behavior appear in *any* question?

Comment: @Robert: "I say this code has well-defined behavior, my coworker says it doesn't, which of us is right?"  It's just another way to phrase "Which side of the boundary am I on?"  Neither side is interesting, only the boundary.

Answer (score -3):

> all other uses of undefined-behavior are actually asking for a
>   citation of some language specification which makes the behavior of a
>   particular coding pattern well-defined, implementation-defined,
>   unspecified, or undefined

Language standard OR other standards: the semantic of pthread functions is defined in the POSIX threads specification, not the C or C++ language.

In fact the UB tag is exactly equivalent to a bug tag: programs with undefined behavior are buggy programs; **it's also equivalent with a correct-program tag which is obviously absurd**.

All programs aim at correctness, correctness is determined by the fine interpretation of the applicable specification. All programming questions end up with the specification of the tools used.

I don't see how it's even controversial that the UB tags must go. It seems to be a **big taboo**, and that requires investigation about the source of the taboo: that people believe there is such thing as a programming task that do not involve avoiding UB is bothering. I wonder what the mental mental of these people are.

Also, the detailed explanation of the UB tag is very silly:

> Questions regarding the various forms of documented undefined behavior
>   in the given programming language.

**What the hell is "documented undefined behavior"?**

I have posted a question on meta regarding that but it vanished; perhaps because the question was too problematic.

Comment: _"I have posted a question on meta regarding that but it vanished"_ That was because you continuously discarded the community's feedback, to the point of a moderator assuming that you were trolling. It was unfortunate, but a constructive exchange is a two-way road.

Comment: @E_net4 Except I did not. I was asking specific questions which were dismissed so your representation is the exact opposite of what happened.

Comment: I check the question again, and I still don't think you were being constructive then. Anyway, it's not like any of our claims weigh more than the [link to the question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/376623/whats-the-purpose-of-the-undefined-behavior-tag-and-when-is-ub-documented), other users with at least 10k reputation can see it for themselves as well.

Comment: @E_net4 1) When is UB considered documented or un-documented? 2) How is "defined" UB different from "neglect" UB, in theory or practice?

Comment: The answer provided to me started with "_There's behavior that's not defined... And then there's Undefined Behavior. You can define behavior that someone simply neglected to define... But Undefined Behavior is defined: it's defined as a situation in which any behavior is legal._" Do you agree with that answer?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're asking _me_ that question, but from my personal knowledge of C++, that answer seems accurate. It wasn't the answer that was problematic, anyway.

Comment: @E_net4 So, when is UB "documented"? When something is explicitly described as UB in the C or C++ std, how is that different from not being defined? (implicitly undefined) And what difference does it make re: UB tag usage?

Comment: @E_net4: That answer was not accurate.  UB is not only those things that the Standard clearly says have behavior that is "undefined", it is also any case that the Standard doesn't assign semantics.  (The Standard is moving in the direction of explicitly stating "behavior is undefined" for each rule that can be broken, but there are still gaps.)  Behavior that's not described and behavior that's described as undefined are both UB.  (Note that even behavior that's explicitly described as undefined can be given well-defined semantics by an implementation)

Comment: @BenVoigt That is interesting. On the other hand, it really doesn't justify the removal of [tag:undefined-behavior]: you can edit its tag description and wiki to no longer contain such inaccuracies, and it would still stand for itself pretty well. [tag:language-lawyer] is significantly broader than the former, and not always about which of the ["well-defined", "unspecified", "implementation-defined", "UB"] bins does something fit into.

Comment: @E_net4: A "synonym" on StackExchange is not transient.  I claimed that every question tagged "undefined-behavior" is actually a language-lawyer question.  The reverse is not true, I never claimed it was, and it has little bearing on the synonym request.

Comment: @BenVoigt even though synonyms make a conversion from one to another, they are not meant to be applied on every _is-a_ relation. We can only agree to disagree at this point.

Comment: @BenVoigt I disagree that UB means L-L: the UB tag isn't a always request for a specific verse and quote, it's request for an explanation of what the std means; L-L usually implies a request for an exact quote (or explanation of a reasonable interpretation when the text is bad, incomplete, or contradictory, which is very often). But at the end it's always a question re: semantic of the language. (And for code that doesn't have UB, the question underneath is "what is the guaranteed behavior?")

Comment: @E_net4 "_you can edit its tag description and wiki to no longer contain such inaccuracies_" It isn't an inaccuracy, it's a fundamental gigantic conceptual error: saying that there is a class of behaviors classified/specified as UB. It's the exact opposite of reality: UB is the absolute lack of a specification of the behavior of a program, lack the absolute zero temperature is the lack of microscopic agitation. And the whole defense of the tag (as it is) is grounded on that absolute misreading. And now I wonder how many people have these ideas.

Comment: @curiousguy: There *is* a group of constructs whose behavior is explicitly specified as undefined.  But that is not the whole of undefined behavior... any construct which is not described at all also has undefined behavior by default, and regarding these, that tag wiki (and the linked answer we've been discussing) gets it totally wrong.